# Spy/stub a request inside a route (through chai.request)

Tags: testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

### The problem

I have an endpoint called `/players` that makes an http request to an external server and I don't want that request to be performed on my tests, but I was not able to figure how I can mock it under this circumstance.

### The code

`test/controllers/test-players.js`

```
// ...

it('returns all players', done => {
  chai.request(app) // the content of app is not relevant
    .get('/players')
    .end((err, res) => {
      expect(err).to.not.exist
      expect(res.body.length).to.equal(3)

      done()
    })
})

// ...
```

`controllers/players.js`

```
const request = require('request')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  request('http://externalendpoint.com', (error, request, body) => {
    res.json(body)
  })
}
```

### Details

I am using:

- Node (v6)
- Express (v4)
- Mocha (v3)
- Chai (v3)
- Sinon (v1.17)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I just intercepted the request using [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock):

```
const fixture = [{id: 1, name: 'User'}, {id: 2, name: 'Admin'}, {id: 3, name: 'Subadmin'}]

nock('https://domain.com')
  .get('/some-endpoint')
  .reply(200, {fixture})

it('returns all players', done => {
  chai.request(app) // the content of app is not relevant
    .get('/players')
    .end((err, res) => {
      expect(err).to.not.exist
      expect(res.body.length).to.equal(3)

      done()
    })
})
```